# What is general implementation of data sending buffer in java?

Tags: java, buffer

I am designing an application which send text in a fixed interval. During this interval, the application is collecting data and store it temporary in a buffer before sending it out (and clear the content of database).

I try not to store them in memory.

Currently I am considering to use H2 embedded database.

What we normally use for buffer implementation in Java? Plain text file? log file?

Comment: Buffers are generally used *instead* of writing to the filesystem or storing in a database. Why do you want to avoid using an in-memory buffer?

Comment: Normally you would buffer in memory, making sure you have enough memory to do this.  You would only use a file or database for very large amounts of data which you would store for long periods of time.

Comment: My application collects statistic figure of another running program, which could generate a lots of data.

Comment: If the interval is short enough, memory buffer would be a good choice. Since this application allow user to set the interval, it may run into risk of Out-of-memory problem.

Comment: I think that if you are going to work with a memory buffer you can use StringBuilder. Please remember that this class is unsynchronized so if you are have multiple threads accessing to it do not forget to synchronize your class internally. Mi suggestion is valid if you are using the JDK 1.5 or a newer version. In the other hand you still have the StringBuffer implementation (thread-safe but slower). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

After read your comments, I think that an implementation for your problem could be:

Create a transactional service in where you collect all the necessary information, store it in 
a StringBuilder, send the information and finally clear the content in database, if any problem arise your database will keep the information, in other words a reliable service.

If you are using multiples threads to recover information keep in mind that StringBuilder is unsynchronized, so if your solution have multiple threads working on the StringBuilder not forget to synchronize your class internally or use StringBuffer (remember that is thread-safe but slower).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Memory buffer or not depends also on your applications needs.
If for example your application must be reliable and manage the recovery when a problem occurs causing a crash, the better approach is to use file and you can recover if some data are not yet treated.

And for such needs there's also the [MOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware)(Message oriented middlware) option, this solution provides many advantages including reliability.but if you dont need reliability and only some  data exchange exist no need to use MOM.

Comment: JMS seems overkill. My application is a small utility program which collects information of running program.

Comment: Yes for this reason I specify in my answer that no need for MOM if it's only a small application :)